# Restart condition trigger event in system dynamics model in Anylogic

Tags: events, anylogic, restart

I have a pretty simple system dynamics model in AnyLogic with units in years. I included an event (trigger type: condition) that stops the inflow into a stock when the stock reaches a value of 2158590 or when time() is a multiple of five; see the images below. I want the event to restart when the stock is <2158590(there is an outflow that removes 1000000) or when time is not a multiple of five. I read through the AnyLogic Help for Events and found this: "If you want your event to continue monitoring the condition after the event has occurred once, end the Action of this event with the code string event.restart();". So I included the restart in the action field, but the simulation stops when 5 years are reached and doesn't restart. I've tried setting up separate events, one for the time component and one for the stock value component, but this also doesn't work. I also tried including another event (trigger type: condition) where the condition is that the stock is < 2158590 or when time is not a multiple of five and the action is USatTarget.restart(), but this also doesn't work; I got this method from this example "https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/acbbe3d0-e4b6-4333-b92d-a3403ca704bb?mode=SETTINGS." I'm not really sure what to attempt next so I would greatly appreciate any help. Please also let me know if I need to provide more information.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are using | instead of || for your or operator

But nevertheless, i would make 2 events, one a cyclic timer that runs every 5 seconds and starts after 5 seconds and another one which is the conditional event that you are using. This because it-s uncertain that time()%5 will work 100% of the time

Then after one of the events is triggered, both would be restarted.